# How to Capture a Picture without Previewing in Android Studio 2019

Tags: java, android-studio

How to Capture a Picture without Previewing in Android Studio use camera2 api

Comment: You should provide some code that displays what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Google is protecting their users from this feature.  You are no longer going to be able to do this as of Android Pie (API 28).  This was first reported as of February of 2018.

"According to a source code commit spotted by XDA Developers, Android P will detect and prevent background applications from accessing the camera."

https://www.androidauthority.com/android-p-camera-restrictions-839076/

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-background-apps-camera/

Since this is going to limit your ability to upgrade this feature, as well as possibly getting your app disabled in the Play store, I'd avoid doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to Display the previews but you need to go through at least 5-6 previews before the image is even decent. You run into a lot of issues where the image is too dark because it hasn't taken in enough light or it is out of focus. So you would need to cycle through many images in the preview. You don't need to display them. Only then can you take an actual picture using the STILL_CAPTURE template.